# MySQL restrict specific login to single ip address

Tags: mysql, windows-server

i am trying to setup a mysql server with some logins that can be accessed from anywhere, and another login ( effectively root access ) from a single machine with a static ip. both machines have a single WAN address and are located in the same hosted server facility. the only firewall present is the one built into the operating system.

Host ( 81.1.1.1 / SERVER-4XP5PS5 / mysql_win64 5.5 / svr2012r2 ):

firewall port translation :

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5001 connectport=3306 connectaddress=81.1.1.1 protocol=tcp
Advanced Firewall Rules->Add inbound open port 'MySQL5001' / port 5001 / tcp / All connection types
```

mysql remote login :

```
create user 'testuser'@'82.2.2.2' identified by 'testpassword';
grant all on *.* to 'testuser'@'82.2.2.2';
```

Client ( 82.2.2.2 / mysql_win32 5.5 / svr2012r2 ):

```
mysql.exe -h81.1.1.1 -P5001 -utestuser -ptestpassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'SERVER-4XP5PS5' (using password: YES)
```

it seems the mysql server on the host thinks the connection is coming from the local machine, but it is not, i am running the mysql connect command from the client machine.

any ideas how to get mysql to get testuser to connect through port 5001 while restricting testuser connections to ip 82.2.2.2 ?

note : it works fine if i lose the ip address requirement and replace 82.2.2.2 with %, but that defeats the purpose of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the setting of `skip-name-resolve`?

Comment: `skip-name-resolve` is off, so i guess it's not a dns cache messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contributions - although i have discovered a work around. Instead of using windows firewall to do port translation, i can just change my.ini and set my desired port. and instead of creating a user i just create the grant :

```
grant all on *.* to 'testuser'@'82.2.2.2' identified by 'testpassword';
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when your computer has a static IP address - say:  81.1.1.1 - that doesn't mean that on the network your computer is recognized as 81.1.1.1 when a connection is attempted.

The address your computer has - when connecting to computers on the internet - uses what's called a "NAT Gateway address".

So... login to 81.1.1.1 and if it's a windows machine browse: http://whatismyipaddress.com

That's your NAT Gateway IP address.

If you have access only to Powershell on 81.1.1.1 - instead of browsing - you can use curl instead.

curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com

Using curl is pretty much your only choice if you're on Linux.

I think your workaround succeeded because mysql command line read the command line argument and passed on validating the real incoming IP address. It used 81.1.1.1 as a mock.

Ah, you'd be a lot better off if you weren't using a static IP at all. If you want help with that post a question like "How to configure your workstation as a fully qualified host on your network".

The answer to your question. How to restrict access to a single IP... You have to set up a VPN and only allow requests from known NAT Gateways. Don't allow NAT Gateways from all of Comcast - otherwise anyone can still get in. Sometimes to get around that you allow authorized users to connect to your network. And then allow connections from the NAT Gateway from there.